# Touch event not working in animation keyframes CSS IOS 14

Tags: css, ios, webview, safari

I try to prevent hold drag when animation *content to left* is running so the animation not stuck using **touch-action**, but when i test in IOS 14 Webview, **touch-action** seem not working properly. Any insight?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px
  height: 100vh;
}

.content-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    animation: ctl-noTouch 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); 
}

@keyframes ctl-noTouch {
  0% {
      transform: translateX(40px); 
      touch-action: none;
  }
  99% {
      transform: translateX(0px); 
      touch-action: none;
  }
  100% {
      transform: translateX(0px); 
      touch-action: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content-box'>
    Content to left
  </div>
</div>
```